# How to get the last alphabetic character in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here, I want to give each character a space except for the last *alphabetic* one:

```
var str = "test"
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += (/*condition*/) ? str[i] 
                              : str[i] + " ";
} 
console.log(result);
```

So it prints "t e s t".

I tried this `(i === str.length - 1)` but it didn't work when a string had period(.) as it's last character ("test.") while I wanna target only alphabetics.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output

Comment: "test" => "t e s t" // "test!" => "t e s t" because in my code I also don't include non-alphabetic characters. @t.niese

Comment: That  `"test"` should become `"t e s t"` is in the question. But how should `"test."` look like?

Comment: What would "don't test." result in?

Comment: @trincot "d o n t t e s t" because I also excluded non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: So `"test!"` has to become `"t e s t"` and the `!` should to be removed?

Comment: @t.niese Exactly, but I've already done the code that removes non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: But if you already have the code that removes the non-alphabetic  characters, then what is the acutal problem?  In the code you show  there is nothing that removes the non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: You already removed non-alphabetic chars, but you have problems with strings with non-alphabetic chars?!

Comment: Yes, I just want a way to target the last alphabetic character, and I'm sorry that I didn't make my question clear enough @sinisake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove all non-alphabetical characters first, and then do a split/join combination to insert the spaces (or use another regex):

```js
var str = "don't test.";
var result = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '').split('').join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"testasdf. asdf asdf asd.d?".replace(/./g,"$& ").replace(/([A-Za-z]) ([^A-Za-z]*)$/, '$1$2')
```

the first replace add a space to all char

the second replace removes the space after the last letter

```js
console.log("testasdf?".replace(/./g,"$& ").replace(/([A-Za-z]) ([^A-Za-z]*)$/, '$1$2'));
console.log("Super test ! Yes".replace(/./g,"$& ").replace(/([A-Za-z]) ([^A-Za-z]*)$/, '$1$2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is such a feature like lookahead assertions.
So it could be

```
str.replace(/(\w)(?=.*\w)/, "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex replace function, you can space out all of your characters like this:

`"test string, with several words.".replace(/\w{2,}/g, match => match.split('').join(' '))`

Explanation

- `\w{2,}` match 2 or more alphabetic characters
- `match.split('').join(' ')` split each match into characters, and rejoin with spaces between